# Creating private cocoapod, git tag issue

Tags: ios, swift, git, cocoapods

I've successfully created a static library, *MyCore*, and created related repository.
Then I created *MyCore.podspec* in this way:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name         = "MyCore"
    s.version      = "0.1.4"
    s.summary      = "..."
    s.description  = "..."
    s.homepage     = "https://foo.com/MyCore"
    s.license      = '...'
    s.platform     = :ios, "8.0"
    s.source       = { :git => "https://foo.com/MyCore.git", :tag => s.version.to_s }
    s.source_files  = 'MyCore/*.swift'
end
```

I run

```
pod spec lint --allow-warnings
```

and the podspec passed the validation.

Nice, than in my project I have podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'MyProject' do

    pod 'MyCore', :git => 'https://foo.com/MyCore.git'

end
```

When I run **'pod install'**, my pod is installed, but not at the last tag **(0.1.4)** as I expect:

```
Installing MyCore 0.1.0
```

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: What does your `Podfile.lock` file say about `MyCore`? Also, what is the output of `pod outdated`?

Answer (score 0):

For private pods that are not stored in a spec repo, Cocoapods cannot find a reference to compare the version number against.

Run the following then to force it to update.

```
pod update
```

Comment: I run 'pod update' but it install 0.1.0 version, not 0.1.4.

Comment: Any chance you are on a different branch other than master?

Comment: no way, I've updated question with a screen of the project's branches/tags

Answer (score 0):

I think in addition to `pod spec lint --allow-warnings` you also have to push the changes.

So this is a complete steps

1. `pod spec lint --allow-warnings` # Assuming that the previous succeeds.
2. `git tag -a 0.1.4`; `git push --tags` # You will now have to create a tag
3. `pod repo push SpecsRepo MyCode.podspecs` # push the podspec file